# Nested CloudFormation Stack Rollback

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In a Nested Stack setup -

1. I have the following - Root Stack, Nested Stack 1, Nested Stack 2.
2. Nested Stack 2 is referencing an output variable from Nested Stack 1

**Question:**
If my Nested Stack 1 is successfully created, but Nested Stack 2 encounters an issue, both the stacks are rolled back. Is there a way only the failed stack is rolled back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly there is not. Parent stack + nested stacks are considered as a **one entity**. If anything fails, everything is rolled back.

If you want to have them be separate, then do not nest your stacks. Instead **extract nested resources** to their own stacks and [export their outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html), so that other stacks can import them. Alternatively, pass the outputs as inputs to the other stacks.

Comment: Thanks, Marcin. The stacks currently are like that and one stack exports and are values are imported by others. We wanted to have them as a single entity so that we could send on invocation. With that being not an option - a custom CLI or CodePipeline is the way to kick the stacks

Comment: @NitinRastogi If you have all your infrastructure as one "single entity", then any failure leads to full stack rollback. Thus I don't see how CLI or CP could prevent this?

Comment: I have multiple independent stacks called being uploaded manually one after the one on CloudFormation. There are around 15 stacks. I have currently written a Python script to stitch them together and if one fails the previous ones are not rolled back. I could use CodePipeline as well, but not sure whether that is worth a change.

Comment: @NitinRastogi Yes, you could use CP. It integrates with CFN, and can deploy and update stacks.